# Why is the refresh indicator not showing on iOS when refreshing the list to fetch its items?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist holding entries in my app. The first app start the list will be empty and the user must log in to fetch/sync his entries. After user logs in I am calling the child.refresh function triggering the refresh of the flat list. The entries are synced correctly and put in the list. On Android I can see the refresh indicator while the list is fetching the entries. But on iOS it doesn't show it and it looks like the app is stuck up until the entries are finally supplied to the list.
What could be the problem? The refresh indicator will not show when there is nothing in the list?

```
   <FlatList
            scrollEnabled={this.props.scroll}
            inverted
            style={styles.full}
            data={this.props.days}
            extraData={this.props.entries}
            refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
             />}
             renderItem={info => (
                    <ListItem
                        day={info.item.day}
                        key={info.item.key}
                        entries={this.props.entries}
                        onPickEntry={this.onPick}
                        scroll={this.SwipeScrollEvent.bind(this)}
                    />
              )}
  />
```

edit: this is how I did handleRefresh:

```
  this.setState({ refreshing: true }, function() { 
      //...
      //when all done
      this.setState({refreshing: false })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this issue only occurs on certain ios devices and not others. I don't know the details, but the spinner seems to be present, but for some reason it's off the top of the screen and the reason seems to have something to do with the "bounce" functionality of FlatList / VirtualizedList.

Adding `bounces={!refreshing}` as a prop seems to fix the issue by disabling the bounce functionality while the contents are loading/refreshing, forcing the spinner to stay within the bounds of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

according the flatlist documentation on the react offcial site [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) you must set refreshing={true} and not refreshControl but

```
onRefresh={() => { // function to call here}
```

Please try this and let me know

PS: refreshControl only applies to listView or scrollview - check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol)

> This component is used inside a ScrollView or ListView to add pull to
>   refresh functionality. When the ScrollView is at scrollY: 0, swiping
>   down triggers an onRefresh event.

Comment: Moving the onRefresh didn't do the trick. I also have mentioned this happens whenever I call the onRefresh from the parent using ref. I am setting and cancelling everything properly. I will edit my post and add my onRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

you should set refreshing while fetch data and pass it directly to FlatList props

> Set this true while waiting for new data from a refresh.

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.props.items}
    numColumns={2}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
    refreshing={this.state.executingRequest}
  />
```